# Column combination matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I want to combine columns of matrices, for example,

```
 A=[1,2,3;4,5,6]';B=[1,3,5;2,9,0]';
```

and I want

```
            C1=[1,2,3;1,3,5]' 
            C2=[1,2,3;2,9,0]' 
            C3=[4,5,6;1,3,5]' 
            C4=[4,5,6;2,9,0]'
```

How do I do that in matlab? Is there a function that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
A=[1,2,3;4,5,6]';
B=[1,3,5;2,9,0]';
Cs = [];
index = 0;

for i = 1:length(A(1,:))
    for j = 1:length(B(1,:))
        index += 1;
        Cs(:,:,index) = [A(:,i), B(:,j)];
    end
end

Cs
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:size(A,2));
C = permute(cat(3, A(:,jj), B(:,ii)), [1 3 2]);
```

The result is a 3D array such that `(C(:,:,1)` is your `C1`, etc:

```
C(:,:,1) =
     1     1
     2     3
     3     5
C(:,:,2) =
     1     2
     2     9
     3     0
C(:,:,3) =
     4     1
     5     3
     6     5
C(:,:,4) =
     4     2
     5     9
     6     0
```